# flask-rq2 error when running the flask app (Unsubscribing channel)

Tags: flask, python-rq, rq

when i try to use flask-rq2 in flask log this logs printed and queue doesn't working at all

```
13:51:26 Worker rq:worker:6cee0c3868f0476a88616b40447a73bc started with PID 295, version 1.15.1
13:51:26 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:6cee0c3868f0476a88616b40447a73bc
13:51:27 Worker rq:worker:eb33c8db94b14e4483addb9a893ea3df started with PID 298, version 1.15.1
13:51:27 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:eb33c8db94b14e4483addb9a893ea3df
13:51:27 *** Listening on default...
13:51:27 Worker rq:worker:eb33c8db94b14e4483addb9a893ea3df: done, quitting
13:51:27 Unsubscribing from channel rq:pubsub:eb33c8db94b14e4483addb9a893ea3df
13:51:27 Worker rq:worker:470a197d0462496e99eefa971a96ca41 started with PID 298, version 1.15.1
13:51:27 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:470a197d0462496e99eefa971a96ca41
13:51:27 *** Listening on low, simple...
13:51:27 Worker rq:worker:470a197d0462496e99eefa971a96ca41: done, quitting
13:51:27 Unsubscribing from channel rq:pubsub:470a197d0462496e99eefa971a96ca41
```

can any one guest what is the problem ?